# bigger tires smaller bike

Tags: wheels, cruiser, 26-inch

If my bike currently has 24 inch wheels, will 26 inch wheels fit?

I have a cruiser with 24 inch wheels an I want to put 26 inch wheels on it, I am not sure they will they fit.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely no. That is too big of a difference in wheel sizes. The frame does not likely have enough room for the larger wheels. If you have rim brakes there would also be the problem of adjusting the brake pad position for the larger wheel. You could always go to a shop or swap wheels from another bike just to see if they will fit, but I think it is very unlikely that they would,

Answer (score 1):

No - the geometry changes, which messes the handling.

Plus rim brakes no longer reach.  Finding 26" rear wheel with a backpedal brake is unlikely.

And finally it'll still be a big heavy beach cruiser but probably with thinner tyres (less cushioning) than it had.

**What is your goal?**

If you want a bike with 26" wheels it will be much cheaper to buy one.  A nice used 26" MTB or rigid commuter will probably cost less than a whole wheelset.

If you want to go faster, a road bike will be a better choice.

Just enjoy your beach cruiser for what it is - a slow casual ride.